# Is there any way I can run a cli command in xcuitest teardown?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcuitest

I'd like to generate `memgraph` file after my UI test, to check leaks. I want to run command like `leaks My_App_Name --outputGrah=~/Desktop/Foo.memgrah` in `teardown`, just before UITest process is finished.
Is there any way I can do this? or Maybe there is a better way to run `leaks` command?
The reason I want to use `leaks` is that it generates `memgraph` file I want to analize after UITest is finished.